# Join two tables using codeginiter framework

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

Hi i have this database which i wanted to join the two tables. In my login model i added the joined table code in it. But i have encountered some error. Here is model below

```
public function login($username, $password){
    $sha_password = sha1($password);
    return $this->db->select('
                      tbl_user.user_id,
                      tbl_user.username,
                      tbl_user.email_address,
                      tbl_user.password,
                      tbl_user.account_type,
                      tbl_profile.id,
                      tbl_profile.profile_type
                      ')
            ->from('tbl_user tu')
            ->join('tbl_profile p', 'tu.account_type=p.id')
            ->where("(tu.email_address = '$username' OR tu.username = '$username')")
            ->where('password', $sha_password)
            ->get()->result_object();
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
      return $query->result();
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

the error goes this way

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'tbl_user.user_id' in 'field list'
```

in my table user i have this field
user_id, username, password, account_type
and in my table profile i have this field
id, profile_type
and i want to joined the two table so that i can get the data in my table profile. Can someone help me out in this? Any help is muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have apply `tbl_user tu` reference for `tbl_user` so replace your select like follows.

```
$this->db->select('
                      tu.user_id,
                      tu.username,
                      tu.email_address,
                      tu.password,
                      tu.account_type,
                      p.id,
                      p.profile_type
                      ');
```

Comment: thanks for the comments! yes i already figured this out. I came up with the same answer to your code ..